# Distinguir nós em uma árvore TRIE

Tags: java, árvore

Tenho uma árvore TRIE com várias palavras (função dicionário), no nó que está o ultimo caractere da palavra preciso de ter um "tipo" dentro deste nó. Preciso distinguir que tipo de palavra é cada uma, por isso preciso de algo que no final de cada palavra (ultimo nó) eu tenha uma variável ou algo do tipo, para saber qual o tipo da palavra.
Como posso fazer isso?

Comment: Poste o código que você já tem, assim fica mais fácil ajudar.